# How priority is given to datatype in overloading functions?

Tags: c++

I am having 3 functions overloaded. How priority is given to datatype in overloading functions?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void myfunc (int i) {
    cout << "int" << endl;
}

void myfunc (double i) {
    cout << "double" << endl;
}

void myfunc (float i) {
    cout << "float" << endl;
}

int main () {
    myfunc(1);
    float x = 1.0;
    myfunc(x);
    myfunc(1.0);
    myfunc(15.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
int
float
double
double
```

How program is deciding to call float or double?

Comment: I don't think your example test what you think it does. A `1` constant is always going to return an `int` and a `1.0, 15.0...` is always going to result in a double. There is no narrowing going on here because you're passing a specific type for each specific function.

Comment: `1.0` is a `double` floating point literal. If you change that to `1.0f` the `float` version will be called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Literals have well-defined types. In particular, [floating-point literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) have type `double` unless suffixed. A suffix of `f` or `F` makes it a literal of type `float` while a suffix of `l` or `L` makes it a literal of type `long double`.

This explains the overload resolution observed:

```
myfunc(x);//calls myfunc(float) since x is a float
myfunc(1.0);//calls myfunc(double) since 1.0 is a double
myfunc(15.0);//calls myfunc(double) since 15.0 is a double
```

Similar reasoning holds for [integer literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) as well - `1` is a literal of type `int`.